# Поиск различных нечётных натуральных делителей чисел в определённом промежутке

Tags: python

```
a = []

for i in range(95632,95650+1):

    b = []
    for j in range(1,i):
        if (j % 2 == 1) and (i % j == 0) :
            b.append(j)

            if len(b) > 6:
                break
    if len(b) == 6:
        b.sort()
        print(b)
[1, 7, 49, 61, 427, 2989]

[1, 5, 25, 1913, 9565, 47825]
```

находит делители только у 2 чисел , а в ответе у 3

вот 3 недостающий  -   `[1, 3, 9, 10627, 31881, 95643]`

в чём проблема?

Comment: `b.sort()` вам не нужен. Вот если бы вы оптимизировали процесс и искали делители только до корня из числа, прибавляя сразу делители парами `j` и `i // j`, тогда нужно было бы их потом сортировать. А в вашем алгоритме они и так от меньших к большим прибавляются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в

```
[1, 3, 9, 10627, 31881, 95643]
```

последним делителем является само число, а в вашем коде второй цикл не доходит до самого числа

```
for j in range(1,i+1):
```

Comment: Невнимательность погубит меня хах, огромное спасибо)